# FIRAnalyticsConnector: building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ipados

When trying to build for Mac using Catalyst, I get the following build error:

`FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRConnectorUtils_77ff1e12be6740765c87f1be0d421683.o), building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator`

The project builds fine for iOS andiPadOS.

Comment: Same problem here with GoogleSignIn. Any answers?

Answer (score 14):

The problem was related to the difference between Firebase/Core and FirebaseCore. The first is a subspec of the Firebase pod that depends on FirebaseAnalytics. The second is only the FirebaseCore pod. Only the latter should be used for macOS.

Solution:
For Catalyst, set use `FirebaseCore` in the PodFile

**Update**: Here is the PodFile:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

def reusepods
end

target 'BatteryCompare' do
    use_frameworks!

#    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end
```

Comment: Can you clarify how to resolve the issue? I don't see any Firebase/Core being used anywhere in my project.

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify. Please check the answer as accepted if it works for you.

Comment: I'm already using Firebase/Core in my PodFile but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Make sure no other module in your PodFile is including FirebaseAnalytics.

Comment: There was a typo in the solution which I corrected: Use ForbaseCore and not Firebase\Core

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, could you share your PodFile? or at least which Firebase modules are you using?

Comment: @AlejandroCotilla and guys.

above solution is not working for me.
pod file link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ge3dBBwbLeqXJGg1ZgrEpZDULQ78FZoD/view
I am facing same issues, I got a below error.

/Users/ios/Desktop/xxxxxx/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRConnectorUtils_d79571aba36a7d46e5c6ca87a6fec1c1.o), building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator, file '/Users/ios/Desktop/xxxxxx/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector' for architecture x86_64

Comment: Works like a charm ! Please note you need to 'pod deintegrate', 'pod clean' and 'pod install' after switching the pod. I had some duplicates errors.

Comment: @Matt there is no 'pod clean' command. What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I didn't say it's a gem to install. It removes pods from project : https://link.medium.com/HfIsOxn1zbb