# How to manage Podfile - Deployment for iPhone, iPad and Mac 10.15

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, macos-catalina

I wanted to try a new feature of Xcode 11 and build my iOS and iPad app, which uses some pods, on my Mac.
[image]

But when I build the project, I always get error from one of the pods (in this project it is Realm):

```
building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator, for architecture x86_64
```

Does anybody know how to correctly manage Podfile for project, which supports iOS, iPadOS and macOS?
This is how my Podfile looks like.

```
project 'MyProject.xcodeproj'

target 'MyProject' do
   use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyProject
   pod 'SnapKit', '~> 5.0.0'
   pod 'RealmSwift'
   pod 'Zip', '~> 1.1'
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
   pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.13.4'
   pod 'Localize-Swift', '~> 2.0'

end
```

Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

It seems one of your pod files not supporting MacOS

what I tend to do is create different targets for MacOS, iOS, then creating a different #def for those different targets. For example:

```
def mainAppPods
  # Pods for main app
  pod 'Alamofire'
  ...
end

def extensionPods
  # Pods for Share Extension
  pod 'Gifu'
  ...
end


target 'ShareExtensionTest' do
  use_frameworks!
  extensionPods
end

target 'ShareExtensionLive' do
  use_frameworks!
  extensionPods
end


target 'Main App Live' do
  use_frameworks!
  mainAppPods
end


target 'Main App Test' do
  use_frameworks!
  mainAppPods

end
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems like the great way to manage the podfile. I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the same in this case https://stackoverflow.com/a/57926682/4942403 , you need to chance 
`pod 'Firebase/Core'`
to 
`pod 'FirebaseCore'`